# Change Rate in R based on the start date up to the current date

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axlCz.png)

Hi can you help me create an object calculating the change rate from the start date up to the current date? I have 4 columns. The 5-yr history, 2022-cases and 2023 cases.

I want to get the change rate between 2023 and 2022 also the 2023 and the 5-yr history.

Automate the change rate for example if it is December 25, 2023, it will add all the cases from dec 21 to 25 and compared it to 2022 cases on the same time period.